# Java graphical issues with game loop and button

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am in the process of making a game that contains a game panel, where a game loop draws the game. It also contains a panel that has a button to start the game loop. The background of the game panel is meant to only be drawn once, at the start of the game. This is because the game graphics shouldn't be erased at each repainting. There are two problems I am having, the background is not initially being drawn, and the button to start the loop gets drawn on the game panel.

I tried to reduce the problem down to its simplest form, here's what I have:

```
public class Graphics_Trouble extends JFrame
{
    private MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
    private JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton start = new JButton("Start");

    public Graphics_Trouble()
    {
        start.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {
                StartActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        menuPanel.add(start);
        add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    private void StartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        mainPanel.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Graphics_Trouble().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
class MainPanel extends JPanel
{
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean first = true;
    public MainPanel()
    {
        timer = new Timer(30, new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                timedAction();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(300, 400);
        return size;
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if(first)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 400);
        }
        first = false;
    }
    public void timedAction()
    {
        repaint();
    }
    public void start()
    {
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

When ran, this yields the frame with the "start" button, but no color, and when the "start" button is pressed the button is drawn onto the other panel, which I did not intend.

Thank you

Comment: Please include all imports so it's easier to copy and paste your code into our compilers to see the result of your code.

Comment: `"...the button to start the loop gets drawn on the game panel"` -- suggests immediately to me that you're not calling `super.paintComponent(g);` in your paintComponent override. Don't make this mistake -- call the method.

Comment: Also, I do not recommend only drawing your background once. Try constantly painting over the last frame; essentially, each time, you paint a background over everything, and paint the parts and whatever.

Answer (score 5):

You're painting is wrong

- Instead of drawing the background only the first time,  you must draw it *every* time
- So create a BufferedImage, draw the background into the image (once), and then within paintComponent draw the image
- Always call `super.paintComopnent(g);` first in your own override method, else you'll see artifacts such as the image of the button, as you're seeing now.
- Be sure that your Timer's listener is "smarter" than it currently is. The object's state should change from the Timer and not the painting method. The painting method should only reflect the state of the object, not change it.

Also:

- Don't add the same component *twice* to the GUI. Add it once and once only.
- If the background image is only to paint the background a uniform color -- to *fill* the JPanel, then simply call `setBackground(Color.BLACK);` in the JPanel's constructor

e.g.,

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainPanel2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 300;
    private static final int PREF_H = 400;
    private static final Color RECT_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final Color COLOR1 = Color.pink;
    private static final Color COLOR2 = new Color(158, 185, 212);
    private BufferedImage background;

    public MainPanel2() {
        background = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = background.createGraphics();
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, COLOR1, 20, 20, COLOR2, true));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, PREF_W, PREF_H);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (background != null) {
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
        }

        // do your other drawing here
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    // timer code

}
```